# Adding beautifulsoup in pycharm

Tags: beautifulsoup, pycharm

How to install beautifulsoup4 in pycharm:

> Click on settings, now look for the project interpreter. This is where you can add beautifulsoup by clicking on the green cross on the right side of the screen.

I did this in pycharm, but there occurs error in installation. The error message is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/Rishi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/beautifuls.py", line 3, in 
> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bs4_*init*_.py", line 175
> `except Exception, e:`
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> Process finished with exit code 1

---

[python.org/pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)
This is the repositories set in the available packages list.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a version of Python 2 on the same machine as your Python 3.4 interpreter?

If so you may want to check to make sure that you are using the correct version of pip. I would suggest removing beautiful soup and re-adding it manually as a test.

```
pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
```

Comment: No there is only python 3.4.1 version and pycharm
When trying to install any package this is the error that pops:

"DEPRECATION: --no-install, --no-download, --build, and --no-clean are deprecated.  See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.
Downloading/unpacking BeautifulSoup4
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement BeautifulSoup4
Cleaning up.
No distributions at all found for BeautifulSoup4
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Rishi\pip\pip.log"

need to install BeautifulSoup4 package 2 run code!!

Comment: Weird. I haven't had any problems running bs4 in PyCharm. What version of PyCharm are you using? Have you tried setting up the project using a venv? Are you using the PyCharm interface or pip from the cmd line? I have the feeling that this is a "dueling banjos" situation between either 2.7 and 3.4 or two libraries you've added via pip. The "Rishi log" portion of your comment clued me into this: https://community.webfaction.com/questions/17055/issues-in-installing-python-packages

Answer (score 0):

You also need to find "beautifulsoup4" (for python 3.x)